# Android Studio build all flavors

Tags: android, android-build-flavors

I have a project that will have many flavors. What do to or how can i build all flavors variants at once? Or at least one by one .... me just hit one time "run"

```
productFlavors

        {
            Svone
                    {
                        applicationId "xx.xxx.xxxx.svone"
                        resValue "string", "app_name", "Svone"

                    }

            Svtwo
                    {
                        applicationId "xx.xxx.xxxx.svtwo"
                        resValue "string", "app_name", "Svtwo"

                    }
        }
```

in my gradle file i have signingConfigs and all my flavors should use the same *.jks

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes

you can use command line

`./gradlew build`

Or using gradle menu in android studio
app -> Tasks -> build -> build

it will generate all apks in app/build/outputs/apk

Answer (score -2):

In Android Studio, when you select `Generate Signed APK`, select `Build Variants` and then select `Release` -> Then it should build whatever you have selected for build type.

See the Build [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html) and the [Configuring Build Variants documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) for more.

Comment: i wana build all flavors at one .... or at least one by one by android studio. I wana build all but not by hand one by one. Just one click for all flavors

Comment: See second link added